# Do AKKA Actors have their own path? if so how do we call them?

Tags: java, akka, actor

I've been told when I create a actor and give it a name, that actor can be identified through a url path i.e if I create a actor

```java
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mySystem");
ActorRef reference = system.actorOf(Props.create(Actor.class),"actorName");
```

then does it mean I'm able contact this actor by sending http request to

```
akka.tcp://mySystem@ip:port/user/actorName
```

? If so how do we call the methods of that Actor.Class though HTTP?

Answer (score 2):

As Matthias suggests, Akka actor doesn't expose an HTTP endpoint.

But yes, each actor has a path and its own reference can be looked up via the path, see [looking up actors by concrete path](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#looking-up-actors-by-concrete-path). That doesn't mean a method can be called on the actor - what you can do is getting its `ActorRef` back by looking up the path, then sending a message to the actor. Sending messages is the ONLY legit way of communicating with an actor. See the sample code below:

```scala
case class Message(payload: String)
def lookupByPath(path: String): Future[ActorRef] = ??? 

val actorRefFuture = lookupByPath(path)
actorRefFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(actorRef) => 
    // This is not allowed in Akka
    // actorRef.sayHello()
    // Sending messages is the only legit way
    actorRef ! Message("hello")
  case Failure(ex) => // error handling
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, One more thing what happens if i create multiple actors with the same ActorRef but a different name? do all of them point to a single instance of my Actor.Class or is a different instance created for each actor name?

Comment: Hi Ashen, if you do `context.actorOf(Props(...), "name-1")` and `context.actorOf(Props(...), "name-2")`, you gonna get 2 different ActorRefs that lives on 2 different paths. The paths are likely to be `<some prefix>/name-1` and `<some prefix>/name-2`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot call an Akka actor's methods via HTTP.